# Como criar um elemento em SVG dinamiacmente?

Tags: javascript, svg

Quero utilizar um número de uma variável e criar vários objetos SVG iguais. Apenas mudar a sua posição e nome em JavaScript.

Como no laço `for` exemplificado no pseudo-código:

```
for(i=0; i<variavel; i++){
    <circle title=circle cx="250" cy="250" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green" />
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão baseada [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034712/2256325).

No fundo crio o elemento novo dentro de uma função, assim o ciclo for fica mais limpo.

```js
var variavel = 10;
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

for (var i = 0; i < variavel; i++) {
    criarCirculo(i);
}

function criarCirculo(tamanho) {
    var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", numeroAleatório(tamanho));
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", numeroAleatório(tamanho));
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 20);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
    svg.appendChild(shape);
}

function numeroAleatório(max) {
    return Math.random() * max + Math.random() * max * 100;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400px" height="400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```